# Is it better to add conditionals to a function in a parent class, or to define separate functions for each subclass?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, subclass

I'm working on a simple game program where a player can control two different tokens - let's call them `Soldier` and `Scout` - which are represented as classes. These classes both inherit from `Actor`, which wraps up their similarities.

Both `Soldier` and `Scout` can attack, and attack targets in the same way, so `Actor` has a function `attack(target)`. However, `Soldier` and `Scout` defend against attacks differently, so the `defend()` function can't do the same thing all the time. (There's several more functions and situations like this, but this provides a good example.)

Here's the question: **how, and where, should I implement `defend()`?**

**Option A**: Implement `defend()` in `Actor`, adding conditionals to change the behavior depending on whether the `Actor` is a `Soldier` or a `Scout`.

```
class Actor:
    def defend(self):
        if self.actor_type == "Soldier":
            # Defend like a Soldier
        elif self.actor_type == "Scout":
            # Defend like a Scout
        else:
            raise TypeError("Invalid actor type: " + self.actor_type)
```

**Option B**: Implement one instance of `defend()` in `Soldier`, using the defense behavior for a `Soldier`, and another instance of `defend()` in `Scout`, using the defense behavior for a `Scout`.

```
class Actor:
    # Stuff both Soldiers and Scouts can do the same way

class Soldier(Actor):
    def defend():
        # Defend like a Soldier

class Scout(Actor):
    def defend():
        # Defend like a Scout
```

Perhaps there's also an Option C? Frankly I'm not quite sure what I mean by "better" - I'm mainly looking to know if one option or the other is supported or castigated by best-practice guidelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely the latter. The former approach requires the parent class to know all its subclasses, which kind-of goes against the point of being able to easily extend your code.